# How to get data from a parse object?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I have a class in parse.com called Messages. I have created a column called sent of type string which stores the object-id of the user to whom the message has to be sent.
In my android app I want to retrieve the messages of the current user.
But my app does not show any messages.

This is how I'm implementing it-

```
public void done(List<ParseObject> postList, ParseException e) {
setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
if (e == null) {
// If there are results, update the list of posts
// and notify the adapter
posts.clear();   //posts is a list of <TextMessage>
//TextMessage is a class which holds the details of Messages (parse object)

for (ParseObject msg : postList) {

if(msg.getParseUser("sent")==ParseUser.getCurrentUser())
{
    TextMessage note = new TextMessage(msg.getObjectId());
    posts.add(note);
}

}
    ((ArrayAdapter<TextMessage>) getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I can't understand why the if conditions are not being implemented, what am I doing wrong.
How else can I retrieve the string in the sent column?
Feel free to ask for any more information required.

Comment: in this line if(msg.getParseUser("sent")==ParseUser.getCurrentUser()), r u comparing strings?

Comment: yes, I am comparing strings here.

Comment: read the docs.. return type of "getCurrentUser()'  is a user object not a string.... ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I am not android expert** but I think your issue is :

**If** you care comparing two strings, you must use `equals()` not `==`

Change `==` to `equals()` everything works

**Note**: `==` checks the reference to the object are equal .

**Note**: `equals()` This method compares this string to the specified object. The result is true if and only if the argument is not null and is a String object that represents the same sequence of characters as this object

[read about equals()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_equals.htm)